# How to run react-native app in Xcode iOS simulator from htdocs folder of xampp

Tags: xcode, macos, react-native, xampp

I am trying to build a react-native app on an Xcode iOS simulator. The react-native project folder is in the htdocs folder of xampp. I get this error message:
[image]

I can run react-native apps on android emulators without issues and I can run apps on iOS simulators when they are not in the htdocs folder of xampp.